# AdminLTE completely hide sidebar when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidebar, adminlte

I'm trying to find a way to completely hide the sidebar, so that its collapsed version with only icons becomes hidden.

Only the top menu's push button becomes visible (the one with 3 dashes that controls sidebar's collapse and expand). Then when push button is clicked the sidebar appears and expands, and when clicked again it collapses and vanishes.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `minified = F` in your sidebar:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      minified = F
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]