# AdminLTE PushMenu not responsive when collapsed, icon is under the sidebar

Tags: jquery, css, adminlte

I want to achieve this kind of menu that would be okay also on mobile below:
[image]

How to do this in AdminLTE v3.2.0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716597/adminlte-completely-hide-sidebar-when-collapsed


this is related to this question. but i need to know the HTML format and if there are custom css and js apart from the adminlte library